# RSA Key and RSA Security

Tags: rsa

Is there any relationship between the RSA keypair standard and RSA security?

Keypair: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29)

Security: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Security

If not, can anyone explain what RSA stands for (so I can keep the two seperate)?

Comment: This is a test, please ignore. What follows the space after the next occurrence of START in this comment is as follows: `Alice $u $ Bob [link](https://stackexchange.com) Carol $v$ David.` and the problem is that the link is not properly formatted. START Alice $u $ Bob [link](https://stackexchange.com) Carol $v$ David.

Comment: This is a test, please ignore. What follows the space after the next occurrence of START in this comment is as follows: `Alice $u$ Bob [link](https://stackexchange.com) Carol $v$ David.` and this time the link is properly formatted. START Alice $u$ Bob [link](https://stackexchange.com) Carol $v$ David.

Comment: This is a test, please ignore. What follows the space after the next occurrence of START in this comment is as follows: `Alice $u$Bob [link](https://stackexchange.com) Carol $v$ David.` and the problem is that the link is not properly formatted. START Alice $u$Bob [link](https://stackexchange.com) Carol $v$ David.

Comment: This is a test, please ignore. What follows the space after the next occurrence of START in this comment is as follows: `Alice $u$Bob [link](https://stackexchange.com) Carol $v$David.` and this time the link is properly formatted. START Alice $u$Bob [link](https://stackexchange.com) Carol $v$David.

Comment: Alice $u $ Bob [link](https://stackexchange.com) Carol $v$ David.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both cases (the company name and the algorithm name), the letters “RSA” stand for the initials of the surnames of Ron Rivest, Adi Shamir, and Leonard Adleman… $R$ivest, $S$hamir, and $A$dleman.

Wrapping it up in short:

- In 1977, they (Ron Rivest, Adi Shamir, and Leonard Adleman) first publicly described an algorithm which was named after them and is commonly known as the [“*RSA public key cryptography algorithm*”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29).
- In 1982, they (Ron Rivest, Adi Shamir, and Leonard Adleman) founded a company to offer cryptographic products and services (including products and services related to their “RSA public key cryptography algorithm”. They named their company [“*RSA Security*”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Security).

Actually, there’s not much to be confused about. RSA is short for the names $R$ivest, $S$hamir, and $A$dleman. The individual context will point either to the company, or the cryptosystem.

Thinking about it, there’s only one moment where I can imagine confusion to kick in: when you forgot to concentrate while reading… as there is a bit of a difference between *“RSA Security”* (which points to the company) and papers talking about *”RSA’s security”* (which means “the security of the RSA algorithm”).

Anyway, the articles you’ve linked to yourself already explain all that and more. Therefore, I can’t help asking myself the same question [DrLecter already asked in a comment: “Did you read the two articles?”](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18065/rsa-key-and-rsa-security#comment39954_18065).